# ASP.NET MVC3 Client validation not working after jQuery update

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am running a project in MVC3 which was using jQuery 1.5.1 . We recently had to move to jQuery 1.8.3, however now the client-side validation is not working anymore.

I tried the solution at [JQuery 1.5 breaks Compare Validate (JQuery Validate 1.8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117458/jquery-1-5-breaks-compare-validate-jquery-validate-1-8) however it is not working. I tried to remove the jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js from my layout and I realized that the client validation was still working if I had the default jQuery 1.5.1 instead of the jQuery 1.8.3, which means the validation must be done somewhere in the default jQuery 1.5.1 of MVC3.

*EDIT* The problem seems to come from jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js since when I removed it, even the old jQuery stopped working.

If someone could help me fix this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Post your code along with a description of where it is failing.

Comment: Hello, it simply goes directly to my controllers when I click on submit, instead of showing the div with the error messages. I have no idea how to debug it to be honest

Comment: Actually, the problem seems to be from jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js , I am trying to do the fix at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117458/jquery-1-5-breaks-compare-validate-jquery-validate-1-8 in this file...

Comment: I think you didnt attach the jquery.min.js correctly. there should be no issues in replacing jquery versions..

Answer (score 0):

My problem was actually jquery.validate.min.js , I simply updated a new version from the CDN website and everything worked perfectly :)

Thanks all !